# setSmallIcon(icon:Icon) and NotificationCompat

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin

currently I have this WET code caused by the fact that NotificationCompat does not support setSmallIcon for a Icon and not a resource-id:

```
  val notification = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentText(intentDescriber!!.userFacingIntentDescription)
                    .setContentTitle(label)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build()
        } else {
            Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap))
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setContentText(intentDescriber!!.userFacingIntentDescription)
                    .setContentTitle(label)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build()
        }
```

Is there a way to make this nicer ( DRY ? ) - the problem is that both builder-classes are different ..

Comment: The Icon class was introduced in SDK 23, so compat cannot support it.

Comment: But it could take a bitmap and in the 23 impl it could use Icon and wrap the bitmap for this SDK level and above

Comment: You can always make your own builder class...

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using reflection, then rather than setting the small icon in the builder, set it in the built notification itself. You can check there for SDK 23, and call setSmallIcon using reflection (it is a public method, but is hidden. I doubt it will change), otherwise set the icon field in the notification.

Comment: Notification has no public setSmallIcon - only the builder has

Comment: Sorry, the docs fooled me. It has a getSmallIcon but not a setSmallIcon. The link to setSmallIcon was to the builder.

Comment: no worries - but maybe delete the answer to clean things up

Comment: reflection would not make this working code nicer IMHO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Short of reflection I suggest creating your own builder interface with two implementations: one for `NotificationCompat.Builder` and one for `Notification.Builder`. You might be repeating "android" but you won't be repeating *yourself*. e.g.:

```
interface NotificationFacadeBuilder<out T> {
    /* facade builder method declarations go here */
    fun build(): T
}

class SupportAppNotificationCompatFacadeBuilder(context: Context)
: NotificationFacadeBuilder<NotificationCompat> {
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    /* facade builder method implementations go here and delegate to `builder` */
    override fun build(): NotificationCompat = TODO()
}

class AppNotificationFacadeBuilder(context: Context)
: NotificationFacadeBuilder<Notification> {
    val builder = Notification.Builder(context)
    /* facade builder method implementations go here and delegate to `builder` */
    override fun build(): Notification = TODO()
}
```

`NotificationFacadeBuilder` (or whatever you decide to call it) will have to declare each common builder method you need and then each implementing class will simply delegate those to their respective, actual builder implementations.